# CSS fixed element in section

Tags: css

I have this div here...

```
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.gallery {
 background-color: #000;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999999;
  top: 10%;
}
```

Now my site is broken up into `<section>` and I am trying to have that element at the top of the section at all times, not that top of the page. How would I accomplish this ?

Comment: Which element? Section or gallery?

Comment: There is no <section> in your code. You need to provide full relevant code lines.

Comment: gallery is the element I want to keep at the top of the section

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: Show us come code for the section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add css `position: relative` to your `<section>`. Then for `.gallery`, change fixed to `position: absolute; top: 0; left; 0;`

Remove that `top; 10%` stuff too...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the position to be absolute and and top: 0;